# .htaccess Redirection with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

If I enter my website's URL with 'www' then it is redirecting me to the main URL of the website but without parameters.

eg:

```
http://www.subdomain.domain.com/param1/param2
```

**redirects to**

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/
```

But in above redirection it is not appending query string after the URL.

**Desired redirection is:**

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/param1/param2
```

I have tried with following code but none worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

in `RewriteCond`, you will have to add a `\` before `.`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ya it seems working.. but if i have a URL like this: http://subdomain.domain.com/about.html then what changes i should made in rule?

Comment: try to remove `www\.`  and tell me results

Comment: i think it was working with www but it worked because i added [NC,R=301,L] in the RewriteRule